# Why does the execution of my jQuery event handlers result in the page scrolling back to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am running some JavaScript on my page. Whenever it catches an event that is attached to an anchor `<a>` element and executes the handler (which I've attached using jQuery) the scroll position resets back to the top of the page. Is there a solution?

Comment: This doesn't happen for no reason. Could you show the relevant code?

Comment: What do you mean by "catches and executes an event"?

Comment: @SLaks: that should be obvious: the event is captured, and summarily killed. EVENT MURDERER!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While handling clicks on `<a>` tags if you leave the `href` attribute as `#` the scroll thing you mention will happen. This is because the browser executes the *default action* at the end of the event chain (this happens because of the so called [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html))

To solve this you have to *prevent the browser's default handling* of the click event, this can be done in different ways:

- replace `href='#'` with `href='javascript:void(0)'`
- return `false` from your event handler function.
- use jQuery's [preventDefault](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29) method

Comment: As inline javascript is usually frowned upon no matter what, it is better to do `return false;` inside the binded function. This will work just fine, though.

Comment: @pablo: you are a genius...:-) spot on.

Comment: you could also do it by capturing the event and using preventDefault like so:

$("a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

Answer (score 5):

One reason might be that you have links that are pointing at "#", and you have events bound to those links. The solution is to do `return false;` at the end of the event function:

```
<a href="#" id="foo">Test</a>
```

And in jQuery:

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    /* do stuff */
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean that whenever you postback to the server, the page is scrolled to the top.
If that's not what you mean, please clarify.

To solve this, you could use Javascript to send `$(window).scrollTop()` along with the postback, then write server-side code that emits more Javascript to scroll back down if it got the parameter.

If you want a more specific solution, please provide more details.